# How to stop a iCloud Drive file or folder download in OS X?

Tags: macos, icloud

I activated iCloud Drive on my MacBook with OS X, and some folders showed as not downloaded yet. **So I clicked on the arrow next to the folder name to download the whole folder from the iCloud to my local MacBook**.

I realized that my current internet connection (I am at my friends place currently) is too slow and therefore blocks all the traffic.

> How can I stop an active download from the iCloud Drive to my local
>   Mac under OS X?

Answer (score 2):

This plugin helped! - lets you select which folders to sync: https://github.com/Obbut/iCloud-Control. **To download it**, go to https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autodesk-sketchbook/id883738213?mt=8 and select the latest zip file. (Right now it's at https://github.com/Obbut/iCloud-Control/releases/download/1.1.0/iCloud.Control.app.zip.)

If it doesn't unzip automatically, unzip it and move it to your Application folder.

From the site:

1. Place the app in your Applications folder
2. Launch it by right/control clicking and choosing "Open" (to prevent gatekeeper from preventing the app to open) and follow the instructions on screen

**Usage**

The following options are provided through a toolbar item in the Finder.

- Remove selected item locally: the selected item(s) will be removed
  from your device, while remaining in iCloud.
- Download selected item: download previously removed files from iCloud. On macOS Sierra, the cloud icon provides the same functionality.
- Publish public link: places a link to the selected file in your clipboard.

**Compatibility**

iCloud Control should work on macOS 10.2 Sierra, and on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: Can you explain more about it and how to install/use it?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide instructions. Enjoy!

Comment: This is how you properly post an answer with a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This great mac utility, [TripMode](https://www.tripmode.ch), should be able to do the trick.

It should be able to block all internet traffic and then you can selectively allow apps through individually. Especially useful with phone personal hotspot to conserve on the data used.

Comment: Why what does it do? An answer should work without the link